# working in jsfiddle, but not in real

Tags: jquery, plugins, qtip

I have this jsfiddle about the qTip 2-plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/QqER5/

This list is opening speechbubbles on "mouseover":

```
<ul id="ul1">
    <li data-browser="firefox">Firefox</li>
    <li data-browser="ie">IE</li>
    <li data-browser="opera">Opera</li>
</ul>
```

I also implemented on a test-server:

http://test81063.test-account.com/info/test.php

but there it´s not working, anybody could tell me why? i do it exactly like the documentation of the plugin want´s me to do it. greetings!

Comment: Console clearly tells that you forgot to inlcude jQuery library

Comment: And there's a `{` missing on line 11. Use the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) to see error messages.

Comment: i addes the { . Now i get syntax error, but everything should be alright, why?

Comment: As Dhaval said, no jQuery. Or rather, it is there but you have to load it before using it. Move the line that includes jQuery to *before* your own script.

Comment: addes to the header, console show´s no more error´s, but speech-bubble not displaying :/ working with jquery 2.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the URL you have provided:

http://test81063.test-account.com/info/test.php

I found that I doesn't included the Jquery file `jQuery 1.8.3` in your php page.

include it and than check the result.

```
<!-- Include either the minifed or production version, NOT both!! -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="qtip/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Optional: imagesLoaded script to better support images inside your tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="qtip/imagesloaded.pkg.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ul1").on('mouseenter', 'li[data-browser]', function (event) {
            var browser = $(this).data('browser');

            $(this).qtip({
                overwrite: false,
                content: '<img src="http://media1.juggledesign.com/qtip2/images/browsers/64-' + browser + '.png" alt="' + browser + '"/>',
                position: {
                    my: 'right center',
                    at: 'left center',
                    target: $(this),
                    viewport: $('#ul1')
                },
                show: {
                    event: event.type,
                    ready: true
                },
                hide: {
                    fixed: true
                }
            }, event); 
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Also add style sheet at your page header and its work fine :

```
<style type="text/css">
        li
        {
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #cef;
            margin: 10px;
            outline: 1px solid #000;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: i included jquery 2.0.3 instead of jquery.qtip.min.js, still not working, any idea´s ?

Comment: added,no error´s displaying, but also no speech-bubble displaying, modified source code :(

Comment: ok now everything is how you wanted: http://test81063.test-account.com/info/test.php , but nothing displaying while "mouseover-event"

Comment: you have missed the style to include in your page add it and it will work definatly.

Answer (score 1):

As Bhavesh Kachhadiya said you need to include jquery, and you need to include it before your code, or the browser won't know what $(document) is.

Include it in the head like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="qtip/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the tooltip is working in your page but it is not visible because of **full-width** `ul`

Your `ul` `width` is in default `100%` now.

reduce it, so that you can make tooltip visible.

apply something like this:

```
#ul1 {
width:250px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: This thing is not needed to do.

Comment: perfect, that was the BUG!

Comment: @user2999787 really which one is your perfect answer :)